# What is Base94 encoding and how does it work?

Tags: encoding

I googled and could not find much information on Base94 encoding. Does anyone has more details about this encoding?

Comment: Did you mean base64?

Comment: No. Base94 and Base64 are 2 different encodings.

Answer (score 7):

Essentially: Base94 encoding takes 9 input bytes of 8 bits each, uses those to construct a 72-bit integer, and then converts that to an 11-digit base-94 number, and encodes that number using the ASCII characters `!` (33) through `~` (126):

```
!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
```

Here is some example code that someone published on GitHub:

https://gist.github.com/iso2022jp/4054241

Comment: Would it be possible to share an example for this please?

Comment: @JayP — ok, added a link above. Hope that helps. It doesn't contain examples of input/output, but does appear to have a test case built in.

Comment: Isn't ASCII char 33 `!` and not `1`?

Comment: @Benjamin — HA! YES. THANK YOU.
Man, that's the first time I've ever accidentally typed `1` by accident when I meant to type `!`. Usually it's the other way around.